# What is the difference between .any() and .any(1)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have come across the `.any()` method several times. I used it quite a few times to check if a particular string is contained in a dataframe. In that case it returns a n array/dataframe (depending on how I wish to structure it) of Trues and Falses depending on whether the string matches the values of the cell. I also found `.any(1)` method but I am not sure how or in which cases I should use it.

Comment: Did you read https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html?

Comment: Just to add a little bit more: `.any(1)` is not a different method to `.any()`, but instead they are the same method that has optional parameters. I recommend looking up Python method Positional and Keyword parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.any(1)` is the same as `.any(axis=1)`, which means look row-wise instead of per column.

With this sample dataframe:

```
   x1  x2  x3
0   1   1   0
1   0   0   0
2   1   0   0
```

See the different outcomes:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('bool.csv')

print(df.any())

>>>
x1     True
x2     True
x3    False
dtype: bool
```

So `.any()` checks if any value in a column is True

```
print(df.any(1))

>>>
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

So `.any(1)` checks if any value in a row is True

Answer (score 0):

The Document is self explanatory, However for the sake of the question.

This is Series and Dataframe methods `any()`. It checks whether any of value in the caller object (Dataframe or series) is not 0 and returns `True` for that. If all values are 0, it will return False.

Note: However, Even if the caller method contains Nan it will not considered 0.

Example DataFrame:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2], "B": [0, 2], "C": [0, 0]})
>>> df
   A  B  C
0  1  0  0
1  2  2  0

>>> df.any()
A     True
B     True
C    False
dtype: bool

>>> df.any(axis='columns')
0    True
1    True
dtype: bool
```

calling `df.any()` column wise.

```
>>> df.any(axis=1)
0    True
1    True
dtype: bool
```

> `any` is true if at least one is true
>
> `any` is False  if all are False

Here is nice [Blog Documentation about any() & all()](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196)  by Guido van Rossum.